# Server running MS SQL getting login request from another server every minute

Tags: windows, sql-server, windows-server-2016, sql, sql-server-2016

I have a Windows Server 2016 virtual machine running IIS 10 and MS SQL Server 2016. Every minute I'm getting a "Login failed for user" message in the event log. Sometimes 3 times per minute. The user that is specified is the name of another server. The servers are unrelated and shouldn't be talking to each other.

[Event Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDyH0.png)

Login failed for user 'Domain\OtherServer'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: [ServerIP]]

[Event Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vI8Ah.png)

I ran a NetStat utility. It shows multiple connections from the IP address of the other server in a Time Wait state. I ran the NetStat utility on the other server and it shows no connection whatsoever to this server.

[Net Stat Utility](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUofi.png)

I tried disabling the SQL Agent on this server, it made no difference. The other server does not have a SQL Agent running.

Any suggestions or troubleshooting steps would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Netstat isn't going to show anything. You need to run a netmon packet capture on the other server for the "minute" and stop it after the logon fails. Netmon will show the process id of the process that is connecting. Should take about five minutes.

Comment: Greg beat me to it. Run a Netmon capture on the source server until you see new events in the event log on the destination server. Then stop the Netmon capture on the source server, filter the capture for the destination server ip address, and find out which process on the source server is responsible for the traffic.

Comment: I was able to capture the conversation. There isn't a Process ID or Name for the conversation. It's listed under <Unknown>

Answer (score 0):

You need to go onto that other server and see which processes connect to youf machine on port 1433. Or a ore harsh one would be to add a rule to windows firewall to block traffic on port 1433 from that machine.